# Getting an all-white screen on deploying Qt Quick demo app Minehunt

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

To test the deployment process I am trying to deploy the included demo app Minehunt. I am able to get it to run, no crashing or errors, but the screen is all white.

I believe this generally means that I am missing plugins. Dependency walker reports no problems, and I even tried including ALL the plugins from the Qt MingW plugins directory, but no such luck.

Here is what I am including so far; Can anyone advise what else I need to add to get it to run?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dlls don't look bad at all. I think, too, that it's your plugins. Even if they are there, there is a good chance, that your program don't find them. Qt is a bit picky where to look by default. You might try `qt.conf`. This is a small textfile you must create in the folder where your executable lies. It contains the path to your Qt plugins.

For instance, in one of my projects I have the followin folder layout:

```
Appfolder
  plugin
    qt
      plugins
        imageformats
        sqldrivers
   myapp.exe
   qt.conf
   ...many dlls...
```

Then I added a qt.conf file to the Appfolder, which has the following content:

```
[Paths] 
Plugins = plugins/qt/plugins
```

My program is Qt 4, but I don't think this aspect of plugin deployment changed in Qt5.
All my qt dlls are in qt. And I add the following PATH: `SET PATH=.\plugins;.\plugins\qt;%PATH%`. Works like a charm on any Windows I ever tried.

Edit:
I then created a .bat file, which does:

```
SET PATH=.\plugins;.\plugins\qt;%PATH%
cd Appfolder
start myapp
```

This was an ugly quick fix, which I did not have the time to replace with something better, yet.

Comment: where did you place the statement SET PATH=.\plugins;.\plugins\qt;%PATH%

Comment: Added to the answer. Doing it with a batch file is ugly. But what you need is to get it running first. Cosmetics can come later. :-)

Comment: I can't quite tell from the indentiation but is your exe in Appfolder/myapp.exe? Also in there alongside it is then Appfolder/qt.conf and Appfolder/plugin so you have just those three things at the root?

Comment: Appfolder contains a folder plugin, the executable and qt.conf, and the batch file, which starts myapp.exe. Additionally it contains a few more libs I need, e.g. the mingw libs and openssl libs. But all Qt libs are in plugin/qt. The qt plugins are in plugin/qt/plugins/.

Comment: You know, I really hope, this does not count as spam, but you can download my app here: http://tellystream.com/get-started-with-tellystream-today/ It shows how you can deploy a Qt app with all necessary libs. **However!** This is a Qt4 app. Keep this in mind. The general layout is most likely the some. But you might need more dlls for Qt5.

Comment: If I have a folder for each plugin in the same directory as my exe I don't understand why I should designate a path in a qt.conf. The exe will automatically look in its own same directory, right? And all the plugins are right there, each in a different folder.

Comment: What can I say? I did not design Qt. The plugins are not normal dlls. They are Qt plugins. I suppose they are not loaded the normal Windows way, but directly by Qt using the QPluginLoader. And the loader expects certain paths. I never really gave it a second thought, I did it as documented and it worked. Meant: Problem solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

If application runs and shows blank screen then that usually indicates two things :

1. All the dependencies (dlls) are *probably* present and detected properly.
2. *Most probably* whats missing is the presence of qml files at the correct location.

In your main.cpp check the path of qml file which you would have given, and see if relatively that folder is present at the same location corresponding to your executable.

Also, instead of running the executable by double clicking, run it through the command line. It might print some messages if it is not able to locate some images/files/other dependencies etc according to the specified paths.

---

Edit 1 :

Add this flag in the .pro file :

```
 CONFIG += console
```

It will give the exact debug message in a console once you run the application.

Comment: **Most probably whats missing is the presence of qml files at the correct location.** True. So it could also be a wrong or missing qmldir. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html

Comment: it shows this in main.cpp: `viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/minehunt/minehunt.qml"));` And I have my qml/ dir in the same level as the exe, and it includes the path specified in main.cpp. This is the minehunt demo app.

Comment: Check in the project for the presence of any 'resource file' in that case.

Comment: +1 from me for the tip CONFIG+=console. Use this together with the environment variable QML_IMPORT_TRACE to get a full debug trace to the console.