# Trouble getting a Qt Reference Document program to work(Minehunt)... its just blank when run... no errors though?

Tags: c++, qt

http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/4.7/demos-declarative-minehunt.html

When I build and run... I just get a blank white rectangle... game is MineHunt.
The source code is in the URL.  I created files and copied and pasted into Qt Creator 4.7.
Running in Linux.

Comment: **sigh** must be epidemic today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503139/getting-an-all-white-screen-on-deploying-qt-quick-demo-app-minehunt/18505792#18505792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to downvote. Deploying qml apps does not seem to be easy for beginners. jdl, I don't know if I can help you. Currently I am only on Linux. But what I did:

I copied the whole folder minehunt in my destination folder (/tmp/mine). When I ran qmake I got:

> WARNING: Include file
>   /tmp/mine/helper/qmlapplicationviewer/qmlapplicationviewer.pri not
>   found

So I also copied the examples/declarative/helper folder into /tmp/mine. 
Looked like this:

```
/tmp
    /mine
      /minehunt
      /helper
```

Then I changed into minhunt, did 'qmake' and 'make'. A few seconds later I had a working minehunt binary in /tmp/mine/minehunt/.

I'll try tomorrow the Windows build.

Edit: Ok, tried now under Windows 7. Qt4.

QtCreator opened. 
Project `...qt\demos\declarative\minehunt\minehunt.pro` 
loaded. Normally in release mode compiled. No problem. A file minehunt.exe was created in `....qt\demos\declarative\minehunt\release`. Started: White screen. Exactly as you described it. In `...qt\demos\declarative\minehunt` I found a folder 'qml'. I moved this folder and the minehunt.exe into another folder (myMineFolder). Simulating a simple deployment this way. Clicked on minehunt.exe -> worked like a charm.

So my folder layout:

```
   myMineFolder
      qml
      minehunt.exe
```

But of course, I have set my PATH variable correctly to my Qt installation.